# How to filter and downsample before FFT?

Tags: filters, fft

I would like to perform STFT on musical signal with defined sampling rate (`44100Hz`).
I would like to get FFT result for smaller range of frequencies than are maximally available 
(not `22050Hz` but for `4000Hz`) so the result will have better frequency resolution.
So I think I should downsample it, but how can you downsample to the frequency
that is not in integer relation to the input frequency (you cannot leave the kth sample)?
Do you do some kind of interpolation to get values of new samples? 
How does it affect the signal?

I also know I should filter out the frequencies higher than `8000Hz` otherwise
the signal would get aliased. Is there some kind of filter revelant for usage in STFT?

All I know about filters is that to get better (more sharp) filter 
you need more coefficents and so it will take more time to calculate. 
I know there are IIR filters and FIR filters. 
I read IIR filters can be unstable but should I care about it if I use a ready implementation (and I assume it's done right)?

Is it better to filter the whole signal (whole audio file)
at once? If I get the infite response from the IIR filter and I filter
the whole signal at once will the energy be most smudged at the end part of the signal?

I also read filters can pose some kind of delay on the frequencies and it differs for different frequencies. How do you analyse and compensate this phenomenon?

**Edit:** I found that you can get FIR with linear delay and that now they are used more often than IIR. But there's still a delay, what does it mean? That the frequency events (like musical notes) will occur later in *sample number* time? What will be this delay?

**Edit2:** When I want to downsample to sampling rate of `8000Hz` I have to filter so there won't be any frequencies over `4000Hz`. Is this practically possible, because I looked at different FIR filters characteristics and they just seem to greatly damp the stopband frequencies not to eliminate them? If I will have just a bit of the high frequencies in the signal, will the signal *look ok* when downsampled (aliasing won't be noticeable)?

Comment: If you use matlab, just use resample function.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I think that maybe I should have used Matlab, but now I use C++ and [SPUC](http://spuc.sourceforge.net/) library.

Comment: A shorter FFT on the same signal won't give you better frequency resolution.  If fact, without perfect interpolation, the resolution will usually be slightly worse.

Comment: What do you mean by shorter FFT? FFT with smaller window? I want to use the same window for `8000Hz` as I would for `44100Hz` so I think it will have better frequency resolution, won't it?

Comment: Frequency resoution is determined by the length of the window in seconds, not the sampling rate or number of samples.  Use longer windows if you want better frequency resolution, and a lower sampling rate if you don't care about higher frequencies

Comment: But FFT bins divide the spectrum equally up to the Nyquist frequency, so if Nyquist frequency is lower (by filtering and downsampling) this gives better resolution (of course high frequencies will be lost in the process, but for high notes you don't need such good resolution).

Comment: @nuoritoveri: You're lowering the Nyquist, but you're also lowering the number of bins, so there's no change in resolution.  When you increase the number of bins relative to the number of samples, you're interpolating, not increasing resolution.  You can do a 10,000 bin FFT on 1 sample, but it's not going to magically give you 10,000 bins of resolution. :)  All the frequency bins will have the same value.

Comment: But I don't want to make the window smaller. I will apply the window of the same size to the downsampled signal (I think this will only make the 'time resolution' worse, but this might be ok for lower notes because they usually 'emerge' longer). Something like here: https://ccrma.stanford.edu/files/papers/stanm28.pdf

Comment: "Window of the same size" meaning the same number of samples or the same length of time?  Only the length of time affects the frequency resolution. [Zero Padding Does Not Buy Spectral Resolution](http://www.ni.com/white-paper/4880/en)

Comment: The same size in samples, so for downsampled signal window will cover larger time interval.

Answer (score 5):

The process of changing the sampling rate by an arbitrary fraction $\frac{n}{k}$ is called resampling.  It is basically just [interpolating](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation) and [decimating](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimation_%28signal_processing%29) at the same time.

It sounds like you are trying to go from 44100 Hz to 4000 Hz.  If so, that requires a sampling rate change of $\frac{40}{441}$, since $44100 * \frac{40}{441} = 4000$.  As a practical matter you don't want to do really large sample rate changes (like decimating by 441) all at once because it is very difficult to implement filters that can do that.  We thus try to break it down a bit into smaller steps.

If you factor the interpolation rate, 40, we see that it is 2 * 2 * 2 * 5.  We can likewise factor the decimation rate to 3 * 3 * 7 * 7.  One simple way to do the resampling, then, would be to do it in four steps like so:

$44100 Hz * \frac{2}{3} * \frac{2}{3} * \frac{2}{7} * \frac{5}{7}$

If you are trying to minimize the computational load you could rearrange the order of the resampling to reduce the sample rate as quickly as possible.  That would make the later resampling steps less computationally intensive because they don't have to work on as many samples.

$44100 Hz * \frac{2}{7} * \frac{2}{3} * \frac{2}{3} * \frac{5}{7}$

You could also combine the two $\frac{2}{3}$ resamples because their product, $\frac{4}{9}$, does not have any large numbers.  That leaves us with the following-

$44100 Hz * \frac{2}{7} * \frac{4}{9} * \frac{5}{7}$

Comment: You use the word *filter* for the component that will perform the interpolation, right? You have to use normal filter to filter the frequencies before? Or there is some kind of filter that does it both?

Comment: Also it was hard for me to understand with fraction downsampling but I made an example and I think I understand it now: Signal sampled with rate `8`: `0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7` will get: `0.25;1.5;2.75;4.25;5,5;6.25` when downsampled to rate `6`.

Comment: A filter can implement both the frequency filtering and the resampling at the same time.  No, your downsampling to 6 samples example is not quite right.  If one of the "8" samples has a period of one time unit, then one of the "6" samples should have a period of $\frac{8}{6}$ time units, so the sequence would be 0, 1.33, 2.67, 4, 5.33, 6.67.

Comment: How do you project such a filter? I found I can design FIR filters with `firls` in octave but you only can specify frequencies there, no new sampling rate.

Comment: I couldn't begin to do the topic justice in a comment.  I highly suggest getting a DSP book that covers decimation, interpolation, and resampling, and studying it.

Answer (score 1):

Answering the last edit:

There is only a delay in FIR filters when the data is coming in real-time and you need to process results before sufficient future samples arrive.  For off-line processing, you can always read ahead in the file to get "future" samples, or even filter backwards in time order, so there needn't be any delay.  But you will still have to deal with incomplete (zero or made-up) filter input data at the beginning and end of the file.

Comment: So this delay is only the result of the fact that you have to feed some samples into the filter before it starts to produce corresponding output?